# set plot limit based on month and day but not year R

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2

I am currently trying to plot data that was collected only during the summer months from July to September in 6 different years. The beginning date (in POSIXlt format because the data resolution is every 30 minutes) of collection sometimes varies in this data, but all data fall within the range July 1st to September 30th. Additionally, there are 6 sites at which data was collected, but they can be separated into groups of three. Thus, my end goal is:

1) To have two, 18-facet plots (3 sites x 6 years) with a fixed date range (POSIXlt) for each x-axis. Currently:

```
ggplot(mydata, x=Date, y=myvariable, color=Site)) + geom_line() +

facet_wrap(~ Site + WY, nrow=3, ncol=6, scale='free_x')
```

If I don't use scale='free_x' I get the whole year with the summer data in an illegible clump as it shows the full 12 month scale in x. If I do use scale='free_x', my data at the 3 sites (rows) don't line up with each other because the start dates are not always consistent.

How do I specify a month/day range so that all years will appear consistent? I've tried `scale_x_datetime()` without success. Sorry to not provide data to provide a workable dataset, but it's thousands of rows. I think the general problem is clear and the solution is probably something obvious I haven't yet figured out. The main issue is using date values in ggplot2 and to have the x-axis be a consistently from July-1 to September-30 regardless of the data date ranges.

Comment: Spoof it. Add a year column separately that you can color/group/fill by, but in your date column pick a single year and set the Dates all in one year.

Comment: Thanks - that's what I ended up doing!